# create object using naviagtion properties and linq error

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create some entities using linq, and must be doing something wrong

```
var ptemp = repository.PackageTemplates.Where(f => f.employeeId == data.EmployeeId).SingleOrDefault();

File file = AddFileStreams(StrToByteArray(data.FileDataIn), data.FileNameForDevice, repository, packageTypeItemId);

// add new packageItemTemplate
var pit = AddPackageItemTemplate((PackageTemplate)ptemp, file, repository, EnumPackageItemTemplatesCommand.DownloadFile, 0);

// Adds package Item for each package
repository.Packages.Where(pi => pi.PackageTemplate == ptemp).ToList().ForEach(pk =>
{
  AddPackageItem(pit, pk, repository);
});
```

The error is in passing the type of `Packages` to another function as part of a `LINQ ForEach()` the type of `pit` has no problems, do I need to create a list first and loop througn it after? I cant seemt o find an explanation.

The error message I recieve is:

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'PackageTemplate'. 
Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported 
in this context.
```

If I change to:

```
  // Adds package Item for each package
            repository.Packages.Where(pi => pi.PackageTemplateId == ptemp.Id).Select(pk => pk).ToList().ForEach(pk =>
            {
              AddPackageItem(pit, pk, repository);
            });
```

and use the ID in the where clause rather than the navigation property then it works, does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Is `PackageTemplate` an object or a property? Otherwise you are using it as if it was.. and if it isn't..

Comment: Its an object, sorry should have included that code (now edited), I also check object is not null before using.

Comment: PS - I just finished WOT series, where do I collect my medal?

Comment: I am yet to finish the series... I hate college :(

Comment: So basically using `Select` and it works? :S

Comment: If you're spending the time studying then the payoff comes later... good luck

Comment: with or without the select (I forgot I added that) the key is using the where based on ID rather than navigation property

Comment: Mmn.. what if you tried `pi.PackageTemplate.Id == ptemp.Id`? Does it give the same error?

Comment: Yes, that works fine. I just wanted to understand what the issue was. Someone has an answer below. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately that's just the way it works.

Note that what does it evaluates the expression tree and converts it to SQL statements or whatever data source you are using. Since it cannot compare entire objects in the same way it can in managed code, it also does no guessing as to whether the two entities are really equal just based on their keys (which are not even always defined).

On the other side, comparing two primitive values is what it *can* always do.